# Jquery onchange is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#customer").autocomplete("barcode.php", {
        selectFirst: true
  });
 });
</script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#customer").change(function (e) {
    var item = $("#customer").val();
    $.post("add", {"data[Sales][item]": item }, function (data) {
      $('#details').html(data);
      });});    
});
</script>
<input type="text"  id='customer'  name="data[Sales][customer]" class="input-small focused" autocomplete='off'>
               <div id='details'></div>
```

Autocomplete is working fine . On change is not working properly . If I enter all text without selecting through autocomplte then onchange script is working . If I selected trough autocompleted then I pressed tab key then onchange is not working . Its not showing any result.

Answer (score 0):

Use .keypress instead of change

[See documentation of keypress](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Comment: I Need to use onchange itself .

Answer (score 0):

You can use as following:

```
$("#customer").autocomplete("barcode.php", {
    selectFirst: true,
    select: function(e, ui) {  

                        alert("selected!");
                        },

                        change: function(e, ui) {  

                           alert("changed!");
                        }
});
     $.post("add", {"data[Sales][item]": item }, function (data) {
       $('#details').html(data);
     });
```

Comment: Check my edited answer.. I'm able to select the value from autocomplete .. after that if I press tab,. then it fires the change event and alert is dispayed.,

Answer (score 0):

var item = $("#customer").val(); ---> Change Here.. That's It.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jQuery autocomplete plugin then use its [onChange method](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change)

Ex.

```
  $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
    selectFirst: true,
    change: function( event, ui ) {
         var item = $("#select01").val();
         $.post("add", {"data[Sales][item]": item }, function (data) {
             $('#details').html(data);
         });
    // Add more code here!
    }
  });
```